# Manage Zaps from Zappier from consol

Tags: zapier-cli

We have a list of zaps part of team. we want to duplicate all of them since we want them all under the same unique owner user. to do that, i have to go over all of them and copy, change manually, write manually the new trigger mail for each one of them, press continue for all steps, one by one from the UI.

So i would like to know if there is a way to manage all zaps using consol / other way to do it with code. (loop over all the zaps, create copy, get the new trigger mail and store it )

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible, but is a good feature request to write into the team about.